# Grouping particular nodes to their parent nodes inside XML

Tags: c#, xml

Below given is my Sample XML:

```
<Response>
    <Transactions>
        <Upload>
            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
            <Name>A</Name>
            <DocumentID>2</DocumentID>
            <Name>B</Name>
        </Upload>
        <Upload>
            <DocumentID>3</DocumentID>
            <Name>C</Name>
            <DocumentID>4</DocumentID>
            <Name>D</Name>
        </Upload>
        <Upload>
            <DocumentID>5</DocumentID>
            <Name>E</Name>
            <DocumentID>6</DocumentID>
            <Name>F</Name>
        </Upload>
    <Transactions>
</Response>
```

Below given is my coming output:

```
<Total>
    <DocumentID>1</DocumentId>
    <DocumentID>2</DocumentId>
    <DocumentID>3</DocumentId>
    <DocumentID>4</DocumentId>
    <DocumentID>5</DocumentId>
    <DocumentID>6</DocumentId>
</Total>
```

I am using the following given code for getting my output:

```
var downloadfolder = @"C:\Users\KUMARMOHANTA\Desktop\New folder\test.xml";

var masterfile = new XDocument();
XElement newDocument = new XElement("Total");
masterfile.Add(newDocument);

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(downloadfolder);

masterfile.Root.Add(xdoc.Descendants("DocumentId"));
masterfile.Save(@"C:\Users\KUMARMOHANTA\Desktop\merged_.xml");
```

But my desired output should be something like this:

```
<Total>
    <Transactions>
        <Upload>
            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
            <DocumentID>2</DocumentID>
        </Upload>
        <Upload>
            <DocumentID>3</DocumentID>
            <DocumentID>4</DocumentID>
        </Upload>
        <Upload>
            <DocumentID>5</DocumentID>
            <DocumentID>6</DocumentID>
        </Upload>
    <Transactions>
</Total>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the element `Transactions` to `Total`. Remove elements with name `Name`. Then save the file.

Try this:

```
var downloadfolder = @"C:\Users\KUMARMOHANTA\Desktop\New folder\test.xml";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(downloadfolder);
xdoc.Root.Name = "Total";
xdoc.Descendants("Upload").Elements("Name").Remove();

xdoc.Save(@"C:\Users\KUMARMOHANTA\Desktop\merged_.xml");
```

Note that your XML example does not close the `Transactions` element.